# TestNG BeforeGroups not being called unless in parent class or local class

Tags: java, testng

First off, I don't *think* that this is [this issue](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/118).

Anyway, this works when I run actualTest:

```
public class Foo {
    @BeforeGroups("Group1")
    public static void doThisFirst() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    @Test(groups="Group1")
    public void actualTest() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

printing out "first" then "test".  This also works:

```
public class Foo {
    @BeforeGroups("Group1")
    public static void doThisFirst() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    public class Bar extends Foo {
        @Test(groups="Group1")
        public void actualTest() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
}
```

But this **doesn't** work, only printing "test" when I run actualTest:

```
public class Foo {
    @BeforeGroups("Group1")
    public static void doThisFirst() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    public class Bar {
        @Test(groups="Group1")
        public void actualTest() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Does a BeforeGroups annotation have to be in the class or on a superclass in order to run?  I don't see anything in the [doc](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) about this.  I've googled around, the link above is the closest thing that I've found.  Does anyone know what I'm missing?

I've also tried the `@BeforeGroups(groups="Group1")` variant.  Same behavior.

As a rule I'd run the group from a suite (usually from maven-surefire-plugin, sometimes from eclipse using the TestNG plugin), but when I'm hunting down specific problems I try to run individual tests (almost always from eclipse) in order to iterate more quickly.

I should also say I have a workaround.  I have a class that has all of my BeforeGroups and AfterGroups methods, then I extend that for any class that needs those methods.  But it seems like bookkeeping that TestNG should be able to do for me.

Comment: How do you run your TestNG suite?

Comment: No I dont think so .. how are your running ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is about contex of test. If you run your test from e.g. IDEA, it will generate following xml:

```
<suite name="Default Suite">
    <test name="testngex">
        <classes>
            <class name="Foo$Bar">
                <methods>
                    <include name="actualTest"/>
                </methods>
             </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

As you see, no information about your @Before method. To make it work you need to have following xml:

```
<suite name="Default Suite">
    <test name="testngex">
        <packages>
            <package name="path.to.foo.class"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And you will get expected result. Anyway to extend BaseTestClass with @Before and @After is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem.
Add `@Test(groups="Group1")` to your `Foo` class